# Beautifulsoup4 problems

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

New to python and trying to do basic webscraping. My code is below along with the error message.  I've spent hours tyring to figure out why I get an error when I pulled this off the internet.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=33.93680995224785&lon=-118.24891999999994#.Xt_LOzpKiUk')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

> File
>   "C:\Users\mariomanfredi\Anaconda\newupload\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder_htmlparser.py",
>   line 325, in **init**
>       super(HTMLParserTreeBuilder, self).**init**(**kwargs)
>
> TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of
>   type

Comment: Runs fine on my machine, are your dependencies correctly installed ?

Comment: Update your bs4 & requests, what python version are you on?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the exact same code you posted on my machine and it seems to be working fine. Are you sure you've installed all the required dependencies correctly?

If it still doesn't work, try using a different parser like lxml. You can install it using `pip install lxml`

lxml is also faster in general.